# Instantiate a generic class with value in Java

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I have a generic class, let's call it Foo, type T and value of T in a string form.
Now I want to create an instance of `Foo<T>` with this value.

The way I do it with non-generic classes:

```
Class<?> cls = Class.forName(fooStr);
```

But how to provide a template parameter to it?

```
String fooStr; //Foo
String typeStr; //Integer, String, e.t.c.
String valueStr;
```

I want to create that instance 
`new Foo<T>(value)`

Foo can be any name from the set of { ChildNode, ParentNode }, so it is resolved at runtime.

Comment: And what's stopping you?

Comment: Don't describe your code. Post it.

Comment: This may be yet another [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). What are you trying to achieve really (different scenarios may require different approaches/solutions/answers?)

Comment: @Pshemo I think, that description is pretty straightforward

Comment: The runtime type of `Foo<T>` is just `Foo`, so the reflection API (which deals with runtime types) has no way to provide a type parameter. You should be able to just call `cls.newInstance(value);`.

Comment: And if Foo can in fact only be ChildNode or ParentNode, reflection is clearly not the right tool for the job (as usual). A simple `if` is sufficient to know what to create, either a ChildNode, or a ParentNode.

Comment: Not quite, your example `Class<?> cls = Class.forName(fooStr);` doesn't create instance of Foo, but instance of Class but later you claim you need instance of Foo. Anyway generics are compiler tool, they are erased at runtime. Maybe there is some way around to achieve your *real* goal but we would need to know what it is and how you want to use this code.

Comment: If you find a way to create a `Foo<ChildNode>` from the strings `"Foo"` and `"ChildNode"`, what will you be using it for? And how? Asking because I don’t see any use where a `Foo<?>` wouldn’t be good enough, and also because it sounds like an XY problem to me too.

Comment: The type parameter of a generic class usually buys us some type safety on compile time. As far as I can see, there is no way it could do that when the type is only created on runtime. So there is no point in what you say you want, except perhaps for the academic exercise.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to make an instance of type `Foo<T>`. You can only make an instance of type `Foo`. The generic paramater `<T>` will be removed by the compiler. It will not be present at runtime. This is how generics work. Generics are only for better type checking and avoiding type casts.